# Accessing file from template

Tags: django, django-templates

I was wondering if there's a way to access/get the path to a file (eg:myfile.pdb) in a directory (eg:tmpdir) from a template (eg:mytemplate.html) in my Django project below. I'm thinking of something like,

```
{{ /tmpdir/myfile.pdb }}
```

inside the template file.

```
MyProject
|
|_myapp
|
|_tmpdir
|     |_myfile.pdb
|
|_templates
|     |_mytemplate.html
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Template language is intentionally being kept simple, that's why you can't do advanced processing using templates. Can you explain why do you need such functionality, so that one can suggest an alternative.

Comment: If it's something you will be using often, write your own context processor. Otherwise include it with the context from your view.

Comment: Selcuk, I need to run some scripts on the files save in tmpdir/. As Drewness suggested, I tried to write a context processor method, def tmp_path(request): 
return {'tmp_path':os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)) + '/tmp', 
}
However, this gives me the entire path, eg: http://localhost:8000/home/....